# Cette année on sent/ressent la crise

Tags: synonymes, préfixes

I have read "Cette année on sent la crise" at https://french.yabla.com/lesson-Feeling-in-French-Sentir-Se-sentir-Ressentir-670 , but I can't find any meaning related to it in the definition of "sentir" in the Larousse dictionary ( https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sentir/72147). However, I find a related meaning in the definition of "ressentir" (https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ressentir/68722) :

> Être particulièrement affecté par quelque chose, éprouver, subir les effets de quelque chose. Exemple: Pays qui ressent les contrecoups de la crise économique.

Thus, it seems obvious to me that "ressentir" may be used in my first sentence. Would it be correct/usual to use "sentir" in it?

Comment: Cette annee on sent la crise.= This year we are smelling the crisis. [haha] Cette annee on ressent la crise. This year we are feeling the [economic] crisis.

Comment: I meant if "sentir" can be used in the sentence with the meaning of "to feel", not "to smell".

Comment: Actually, there is another phrasing to consider: "*Ça sent la crise à plein nez*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*On sent la crise* is correct and idiomatic.

The meaning is close to the one of *on ressent la crise* but *sentir* is more direct, physical here (we feel the pain of the crisis) while *ressentir* is more indirect, emotional (we feel the consequences of the crisis).

[TLFi Sentir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sentir)

> **I. −** [Le suj. désigne un être vivant doué de sensibilité] Percevoir, éprouver une sensation, une impression.
>   **A. −** [Par l'intermédiaire des sens (excepté la vue et l'ouïe)]
>   **1.** Percevoir, éprouver une sensation physique qui renseigne sur l'état de l'organisme ou sur le milieu extérieur.

[TLFi Ressentir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ressentir)

> **I. −** Empl. trans.
>   ...
>   **B. −** Éprouver vivement dans son âme ou dans son esprit l'effet d'une cause extérieure.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "sentir" is primary interpreted as "to smell" but it can also means "to feel".

*Je sens que cette année va être une bonne année pour nos affaires.*

I feel this year will be good for our business.

This kind of expression is common in French and some others languages based on Latin.

**Example:** I feel bad

- (French) *je me sens mal.*
- (Italian) *mi sento male.*
- (Spanish) *me siento mal.*